# html5 banner and a xls file that contain codes to redirect the banner

Tags: wordpress, html, xls

I have a banner in html5, i have all the files, imagens that will be displayed on banner and index.html, this file contain all codes.

Its ok, i upload all the files into my host server, and i use this code to show the banner.

```
<div align="center"><iframe src="http://www.edgarlisboa.com.br/wp-content/superbanner/index.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height = "90" width = "728">
```

but, they send me another file, A xls file, and i need to insert it into the banner, this file will redirect when they click on banner, and contain a code like google analytics. I really need to insert this xls into the banner.

I use Wordpress and locaweb server host.

Comment: Please edit the code that's failing into the question. People don't want to have to try to decipher an image of code.

Comment: This doesn't sound possible.